# What's the regex to return the following

Tags: regex

I need the regex that returns the following from a webpage's code, I'm searching whithin Dreamweaver in the code of the page:

```
<body>
**** lines of HTML code (anything)***
<div class="pg">
```

sorry I'm into a situation that only regex is the solution, i'm so new to it.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a regex:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  Instead, parse the DOM.

Comment: But when I want to search within code using Dreamweaver and the only option is "Use Regular Expression".

Comment: If you're trying to extract certain elements from your HTML, then use a DOM Parser (eg PHP's DOMElement (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)).

Comment: @Jack: Do you understand the difference between parsing and textual search? How would PHP help in Dreamweaver?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Yes, I do.  Why should he pick out HTML elements in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
<body>[\s\S]*<div> class="pg">
```

you need `[\s\S]` because `.` probably won't match `\n` (unless Dreamweaver has a checkbox for multiline mode or something)